# Error while installing Debian 7 on a virtual machine (Failure trying to run: chroot /target mount -t proc proc/proc)

Tags: debian, virtualbox, vmware

I tried installing Debian wheezy on both Virtualbox and VMWare Player, but I incur everytime in the same error, Failure trying to run: chroot /target mount -t proc proc/proc.
Debian is 7.6.0 amd64, using the iso downloaded from the official website. I'm running on Windows 7, and the error occurs during the actual installation.

[image]
I can't figure out how to solve this issue, and neither what the issue is. Help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some more details. How exactly are you installing Debian? Which Debian? Are you using an .iso, if so, where did you get it? What is your host OS? When exactly does this error occur?

Comment: Added the info!

Comment: Thanks, please also add the details of how you set up the virtual machine. Is it a 64bit VM? Also see [here](http://www.debianitalia.org/forum/installazione/probemi-installazione-debian-wheezy?page=1). Based on your error message, your Italian is better than mine, but it seems to be related to your `/` partition not being formatted. Have you formatted the `/` partition?

Comment: Have you tried running a checksum on the ISO you downloaded? This type of error can happen when the installation media becomes corrupt.

Comment: I did read that, but not thoroughly apparently. It's a bug with the installer that happens if you choose the italian language, apparently, it doesn't create the directory /target/proc. Pretty strange, but anyway, you have my thanks!

Comment: @Dodicin you're very welcome. If you could take the time to post that as an answer, we would appreciate it. That way, you can accept it and the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug with the installer that happens if you choose the italian language, and it doesn't create the directory /target/proc. Pretty strange, but anyway, I fixed it by changing language in the installation.